# Cypress with amplify-js - ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: angular, cypress, amplifyjs

I've just upgraded to Cypress 10 and am now receiving issues from the amplify auth library which I'm using to log interactive users into the site under test. I've made a `cy` extension for this.

It's a known issue in the sdk that it uses this `global` variable which is overcome in angular by polyfilling it with:

```
/**
 *  AWS Amplify - Currently, the newest versions of Angular (6+) do not provide the shim for the
 *   global object which was provided in previous versions.
 */
(window as any).global = window;
```

I've tried adding that in a number of places for Cypress 10:

- in the extension file
- in the cypress config file
- in the support file

But with no luck.

FWIW, [the gist of the extension](https://gist.github.com/alastair-todd/c6392fb092c6ffd9498d2b85738a8b68)

This is the full stack trace:

> ReferenceError The following error originated from your test code, not
> from Cypress.
>
> > global is not defined
>
> When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code
> it will automatically fail the current test.
>
> Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.
>
> We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure. View
> stack trace  Print to console
> at node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/node_modules/buffer/index.js
> (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\e2e.ts:12878:37)
> at __require2 (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\e2e.ts:17:52)
> at eval (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\e2e.ts:27843:31)
> at eval (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\e2e.ts:33508:3)
> at eval () From previous event:
> at runScriptsFromUrls (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:165206:136)
> at Object.runScripts (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:165221:12)
> at $Cypress.onSpecWindow (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:153378:75)

I've tried adding this at the top of the extension file:

```
let global = {};
(window as any).global = window;

/**
 * amplify-js / cognito auth helper
 * specific personas are logged-in and their tokens are cached to save on round-trips.
 */
import Auth, { CognitoUser } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the new `esbuild` bundler which is apparently WIP, but which some kind souls have polyfilled.

(what this all means I've no idea)

I had previously worked around this with the new npm `overrides` directive:

```
"overrides": {
    "@aws-amplify/auth": {
      "amazon-cognito-identity-js": {
        "buffer": "6.0.3"
      }
    }
  }
```

which I don't like as it has potential side-effects now and in the future.

Polyfilling node is the better approach, which is [discussed in more detail here](https://github.com/remorses/esbuild-plugins), but in a nutshell, updating Cypress config thus:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {

    async setupNodeEvents(on: Cypress.PluginEvents, config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
      // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      const bundler = createBundler({
        plugins: [
          NodeModulesPolyfills(),
          GlobalsPolyfills({
            process: true,
            buffer: true
          }),
          createEsbuildPlugin(config)
        ]
      });

      on('file:preprocessor', bundler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having two issues when running cypress test where I need to download csv or excel file plus read those files and validate header and row count - I implemented solution mention at https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__download but was having issue running the test based on path and neat-csv import i.e Process not defined or Buffer not defined. I was able to resolve above issues based on above solution but with slight variation ..

npm install @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill

npm install @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill

under cypress.config.js

const { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } = require("@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill")

const { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } = require("@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill")

e2e section will

````
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config ){
      const bundler = createBundler({
        plugins: [
          NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
          NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
            process: true,
            buffer: true
          }),
          createEsbuildPlugin(config)
        ],
      });
      on("file:preprocessor", bundler);
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
      return config;
    },
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/features/**/*.feature",
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
}```
````